# Postfix timeout after helo

Tags: postfix

I set-up a local Postfix server in my company to relay email from an old windows software that doesn't support SMTP authentification.

I successfuly sent some test emails with telnet and outlook from windows. 
Then, i setup the old software "winfax expert 9" with this SMTP and now i'm stuck with this error that just keep showing up in the mail.log file of the local SMTP server:

```
Jan  4 09:26:37 Helium postfix/smtpd[29089]: connect from unknown[192.168.1.107]
Jan  4 09:29:19 Helium postfix/smtpd[29087]: timeout after HELO from unknown[192.168.1.107]
Jan  4 09:29:19 Helium postfix/smtpd[29087]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.1.107]
```

It seems to be a software failure from "winfax expert 9", how can i confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the software connects to postfix and then does nothing would indicate the issue lies on that side.

Have you tested this software against any other mail server systems ?

It may be, for instance, that the winfax software is unable to cope with the modern EHLO 250 multiline response (AKA CAPABILITIES) sent back by postfix; if this is the case, you can try disabling this for a dedicated smtpd(8) service only used by the winfax software.

You may want to read up a bit on HELO vs. EHLO, and postfix workarounds such as http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps

Comment: Well it doesn't work with the ISP's SMTP which was supporting the SMTP requests of this software before. The local Postfix configuration support both HELO and ELHO commands.

Comment: It was a software failure, i finaly switched to Hylafax